# Scatter graph to show margin and revenue for a series of projects

Tags: charts

Can a scatter graph show non-chronological data - For a series of projects I want to plot the margin on the Y-axis and the revenue generated on the X-axis.  Projects will change position each month as the figures are updated

```
              Revenue   Gross Margin
Project 1    15,815     32%
Project 2    46,760     32%
Project 3    82,655     22%
Project 4    36,000     75%
Project 5    155,820    40%
Project 6    151,752    58%
Project 7    173,678    52%
Project 8    197,090    54%
Project 9    148,750    74%
Project 10   200,800    62%
```

Comment: What software are you using? Excel? Open Office?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is yes.

This is how you do it in Excel:

1. Select your data
2. Click the Insert tab
3. Click the scatter graph icon and choose the basic graph
4. Your graph will now have Margin on the Y Axis and Revenue on the X Axis.

[image: An example graph]